How to prove that the eigenvalues of a positive definite M-matrix are invariant after such transformation?
For a positive definite M-matrix such as
$$\mathbf{A}=
\begin{bmatrix}
2.5 & -0.5 & -1.0
\newline
-0.5 & 3.0 & -1.5
\newline
-1.0 & -1.5 & 4.0
\newline
\end{bmatrix}$$
Applying such transformation
$$\mathbf{A}_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
2.5 & -0.5*(a/b) & -1.0*(a/c)
\newline
-0.5*(b/a) & 3.0 & -1.5*(b/c)
\newline
-1.0*(c/a) & -1.5*(c/b) & 4.0
\newline
\end{bmatrix}$$
, where a, b and c are all real positive numbers. Can it be proved that the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{A}_1$ are same?

This has been verified by numerical calcuations.

Isn’t this simply a consequence of $A$ and $A_1$ being similar matrices? In particular, if $P = \mathrm{diag}(a,b,c)$, then $A_1 = P A P^{-1}$.

@Pranay Please transform your comment into an answer.

Turning my comment into an answer: This is simply a consequence of $A$ and $A_1$ being similar matrices. To see this, note that $A_1= P A P^{-1}$, where $P = \mathrm{diag}(a,b,c)$. There is no need to assume $A$ is positive definite, and there is no need to assume $a,b,c$ are positive, they just have to be nonzero for $P$ to have an inverse.
